# How do I extract data from unspaced strings?

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I need to extract data from four strings that have been parsed in BeautifulSoup. They are:

```
Arkansas72.21:59 AM76.29:04 AM5.22977.37:59 AM

Ashley71.93:39 AM78.78:59 AM0.53678.78:59 AM

Bradley72.64:49 AM77.28:59 AM2.41877.28:49 AM

Chicot-40.19:04 AM-40.19:04 AM2.573-40.112:09 AM
```

The data from the first string, for example, is Arkansas, 72.1, 1:59 AM, 76.2, 9:04 AM, 5.2, 29, 77.3, and 7:59 AM. Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: full code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def scraper():

    #Arkansas State Plant Board Weather Web data
    url1 = 'http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx'

    #opens  url and parses HTML into Unicode
    page1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1, 'lxml')

    #print(soup.get_text()) gives a single Unicode string of relevant data in strings from the url
    #Without print(), returns everything in without proper spacing
    sp1 = soup1.get_text()

    #datasp1 is the chunk with the website data in it so the search for Arkansas doesn't return the header
    #everything else finds locations for Unicode strings for first four stations
    start1 = sp1.find('Today')
    end1 = sp1.find('new Sys.')
    datasp1 = sp1[start1:end1-10]

    startArkansas = datasp1.find('Arkansas')
    startAshley = datasp1.find('Ashley')
    dataArkansas = datasp1[startArkansas:startAshley-2]

    startBradley = datasp1.find('Bradley')
    dataAshley = datasp1[startAshley:startBradley-2]

    startChicot = datasp1.find('Chicot')
    dataBradley = datasp1[startBradley:startChicot-2]

    startCleveland = datasp1.find('Cleveland')
    dataChicot = datasp1[startChicot:startCleveland-2]


    print(dataArkansas)
    print(dataAshley)
    print(dataBradley)
    print(dataChicot)
```

Comment: Can you also show the `BeautifulSoup` specific part? I suspect the problem could be in how you've extracted this data from the HTML.

Comment: you can do it regular expressions

Comment: @Copperfield:  True, regular expressions would fit the bill.  But I think alecxe is correct in thinking this is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Comment: It all depends on how consistent the values are. Are they always the same, otherwise it will be difficult to determine what something like `5.22977.3` in the first line breaks into. could be: `5.22 97 7.3` or `5.2 29 77.3` The same will happen with times. is it `-40.11 2:09AM` or `-40.1 12:09AM` unless there are explicit rules to the data you will not be able to properly parse the data.

Comment: http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx  The data for temperatures is always one decimal place, but the times and third to last value could be multiple characters long/

Comment: What is the point of loading the page into beautiful soup, for then only retrieving the text with `get_text()`?

Comment: Also, welcome to SO :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just improve the way you extract the tabular data. I would use [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to read it into the *dataframe* which, I'm pretty sure, you would find convenient to work with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx", attrs={"id": "MainContent_GridView1"})[0]
print(df)
```

Comment: How do i get each of the table values as independent variables?

Comment: @MichaelFisher yeah, if you have not used pandas before that, please take some time researching how to work with it. It's worth it though. You can iterate over it in many different ways, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe.

Comment: This is about 100x easier than what I was doing before. I'll look into pandas more. I'm brand new to Python.

Comment: One more thing: since all the rows and columns start at 0, trying to get each of the values results in pulling an entire column from station to time of high. Is there a way to prevent this or work around this?

Comment: @MichaelFisher okay, could you show how you iterate over the frame currently? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFisher looks good. Do you mean you have the header row there as well? You can skip it via `next()`, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/a0bb62dceb3fc4ca68c0f48ae24c0fbd

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do, and I probably should have made this clear first, is just take all the data from the Arkansas row, put it into separate variables like the headers say, and do this for only the first four rows. This also why I'm trying to learn how to get values one at a time from the table.

Comment: @MichaelFisher ah, I think I get it, you probably need just to slice the row: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/a0bb62dceb3fc4ca68c0f48ae24c0fbd. There is also a more pandas-specific solution to this, by the way.

Comment: I meant rows as only Arkansas, Ashley, Bradley, and Chicot. In a regular table these would be rows, not columns. I guess in pandas these are indexes?

Comment: @MichaelFisher yeah, columns would be dataframe series. If you want to get the first column as a list: `df[0].tolist()[1:]` (slicing the header row). Hope that helps.

Comment: If using pandas you can just `df = pd.read_html("http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx", attrs={"id": "MainContent_GridView1"})[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use beautifulsoup to parse the html page and retrieve your data:

```
url1 = 'http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx'

#opens  url and parses HTML into Unicode
page1 = urlopen(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1)

# get the table
table = soup1.find(id='MainContent_GridView1')

# find the headers
headers = [h.get_text() for h in table.find_all('th')]

# retrieve data
data = {}
tr_elems = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in tr_elems:
    tr_content = [td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    if tr_content:
        data[tr_content[0]] = dict(zip(headers[1:], tr_content[1:]))

print(data)
```

This example will shows:

```
{
  "Greene West": {
    "Low Temp  (\u00b0F)": "67.7",
    "Time Of High": "10:19 AM",
    "Wind Speed (MPH)": "0.6",
    "High Temp  (\u00b0F)": "83.2",
    "Wind Dir (\u00b0)": "20",
    "Time Of Low": "6:04 AM",
    "Current Time": "10:19 AM",
    "Current Temp  (\u00b0F)": "83.2"
  },
  "Cleveland": {
    "Low Temp  (\u00b0F)": "70.8",
    "Time Of High": "10:14 AM",
    "Wind Speed (MPH)": "1.9",
    [.....]

}
```